# SIGTRAP NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm getting a SIGTRAP with this function

```
- (void)initFetchRequest
{    
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = document.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Shindy" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    // Configure the request's entity, and optionally its predicate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"details" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                              initWithFetchRequest:request
                                              managedObjectContext:context
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                              cacheName:nil];

    // SIGTRAP here

    NSError *error = nil;
    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}
```

Right where I commented. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. The console isn't giving me anything. And the specifics of the crash are just a 0__kill.

A note I'd like to add is that when the view with this function is first loaded, there is no crash. But when I segue to another view, add some objects to Core Data, and then dismiss the view. My original view (the one in question) suddenly throws the SIGTRAP error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding an exception break point and check http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: I can't because the breakpoint stops the first time I'm on the view, but the crash doesn't occur until I segue back to it.

Comment: Never mind, I noticed I could edit the breakpoint to be ignored a specified number of times. That led me to discover that the SIGTRAP is not occurring where I thought it was. In fact, It doesn't appear to be occurring anywhere in the file :(

Comment: Perhaps, the error is coming from with the `fetchedResultsController` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using two references to `NSManagedObjectContext`,

- `context` (for the fetched results controller) and
- `self.managedObjectContext` (for the fetch request's entity).

You should verify if these are indeed the same. In any event, it is much better to use the same variable for the FRC and its initializing fetch request.

Another source of the error could be your sort descriptor. Check if it is working elsewhere as expected.

Comment: Well, I figured out the SIGTRAP wasn't occurring within this function like I thought.